# How can I make testRigor find this input the right way?

Tags: testrigor

I'm trying to make testRigor find this input with no success:
[the input we're trying to put data on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6InkC.png)

```
<td title="" id="ember857" class="right aligned middle aligned ember-view">R$&nbsp;0,00</td>
```

The ID is not the same always so we can't use it.
Already Tried:

```
generate by regex "[1-9]{6}", then enter into the second input "R$ 0,00" and save as "custoProdutos"
generate by regex "[1-9]{6}", then enter into the first input "R$ 0,00" and save as "custoProdutos"
generate by regex "[1-9]{6}", then enter into input "R$ 0,00" and save as "custoProdutos"
generate by regex "[1-9]{6}", then enter into input "R$&nbsp0,00" and save as "custoProdutos"
generate by regex "[1-9]{6}", then enter into input "R$ 0,00" below the "Vl. Un." and save as "custoProdutos"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, try the relative location:

```
generate by regex "[1-9]{6}", then enter into the third input on the right of  "eerenlkrwlfxr" and save as "custoProdutos"
```

or partial match:

```
generate by regex "[1-9]{6}", then enter into the second input "R$" and save as "custoProdutos"
```

Comment: Thanks, I used the partial match and it worked perfectly, thanks!